# Read data from a single record OR more records

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a query which gives data from one person or from more persons.
The data for one person is presented with JSON as:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( 
 [a2a_Person] => Array ( 
 [pid] => Person1 
 [a2a_PersonName] => Array ( 
 [a2a_PersonNameFirstName] => Array ( [a2a_PersonNameFirstName] => Aagje )  
 [a2a_PersonNameLastName] => Array ( [a2a_PersonNameLastName] => Baltus ) ) ....
```

If there are more persons then the data is presented as

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( 
 [a2a_Person] => Array ( 
  [0] => Array ( 
  [pid] => Person1 [a2a_PersonName] => Array ( 
  [a2a_PersonNameFirstName] => Array ( [a2a_PersonNameFirstName] => Walig )
  [a2a_PersonNamePatronym] => Array ( ) 
  [a2a_PersonNamePrefixLastName] => Array ( ) 
  [a2a_PersonNameLastName] => Array ( [a2a_PersonNameLastName] => Verdugt ) ) [a2a_Gender] => Array ( [a2a_Gender] => Man ) 
 [1] => Array ( 
  [pid] => Person2 
  [a2a_PersonName] => Array ( 
  [a2a_PersonNameFirstName] => Array ( [a2a_PersonNameFirstName] => Huibert ) [a2a_PersonNamePatronym.....
```

My question is now : how can i determine if I have more Person-records so i can acces the data correct way.

And what is the best way to acces the data. Must I first check the definition and write different code.

Thanks,
Fred

Comment: count that array and then loop it.

Comment: ? I don't understand it